# Executing jQuery function on many adjacent divs

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-events

I have this jQuery function:

```
function displayKeyboard(event) {
$('#keyboard')
.keyboard({
alwaysOpen: false
});
}
```

It is supposed to be executed by two buttons on the same page. Each of the button opens a different div. The keyboard shows on the top div (flights) but not on the next one. If I swap  the arrangement of the divs, the reverse happen. Here is how I am calling the divs:

```
 <?php echo $this->element('Flights/flights') ?>
 <?php echo $this->element('Hotels/hotels') ?>
```

Anyone who knows what could be happening please?

Comment: `$('#keyboard')` how many keyboards do you have?

Comment: I'm guessing you have two buttons with the ID #keyboard, and you can't do that as ID's are unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: There's only one $('#keyboard') which is the id of the input field, the buttons have different ids. It's like I'm reusing the input field with the same id in two divs. Thanks.